# Hibernate not using schema and catalog name in id generation with strategy increment

Tags: hibernate, orm, jakarta-ee, jboss, seam

I am using the hibernate increment strategy to create my IDs on my entities.

```
@GenericGenerator(name="increment-strategy", strategy="increment")
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="increment=strategy")
@Column(name="HDR_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getHdrId(){
     return this.hdrId;
}
```

The entity has the following table annotation

```
@Table(name = "PORDER.PUB.PO_HEADER", schema = "UVOSi", catalog = "VIRT_UVOS")
```

Please note I have two datasources.

When I try to insert an entity Hibernate creates the following SQL statement:
select max(hdr_id) from PORDER.PUB.PO_HEADER
which causes the following error: Group specified is ambiguous, resubmit the query by fully qualifying group name.

When I create a query by hand with entityManager.createQuery()
hibernate uses the fully qualified name

```
select XXX from VIRT_UVOS.UVOSi.PORDER.PUB.PO_HEADER
```

and that works fine. 
So how do I get Hibernate to use the fully qualified name in the Id autogeneration?

Btw. I am using Hibernate 3.2 and Seam 2.2 running on JBoss 4.2.3

Regards

Immo

Comment: This also occurs using the xml to wire up your tables.  This must be a bug...

Answer (score 0):

*I think* that Hibernate should honor the `catalog` and `schema` attributes of the `@Table` when using the `increment` strategy. This may be a bug and I couldn't find anything close in the [Jira](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/ANN) of Hibernate Annotations. I would raise an issue.

**Update:** Actually, I just noticed that JPA 2.0 introduced new [`schema`](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/ANN) and [`catalog`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#catalog()) attributes on the [`@SequenceGenerator`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) annotation. I'm thus not sure what to expect from a JPA 1.0 provider (and my initial assumption that the JPA provider should use the information from the `@Table` annotation might be wrong), the spec isn't clear about that (or I couldn't find the information).